# iterating through length of a list

Tags: python

given a list of nums, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3
...how do i solve this?
i tried using the range function but that doesnt seem to work..
for example,

```
def myfunc(mylist):
     for i in range(0, len(mylist) - 1):
         return mylist[1] == 3 and mylist[i + 1] == 3

myfunc([4, 3, 3])
returns false
```

I'm a little confused actually
 how to iterate through index count

```
def myfunc(mylist):
     for i in range(0, len(mylist) - 1):
         return mylist[1] == 3 and mylist[i + 1] == 3

myfunc([4, 3, 3])
returns false

expected result = True
actual output = False
```

Comment: It returns True for me

Comment: use enumerate to get current index of list while iterating.

Comment: that was helpful, but again, returning false when the last item in the list is 3

Answer (score 2):

```py
return mylist[i] == 3 and mylist[i + 1] == 3
```

This always returns after checking only once. Instead, use

```py
if mylist[i] == 3 and mylist[i + 1] == 3: return True
```

Comment: Would work much better if you compare index `i+1` with index `i` instead of with `1`

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` you can compare the list with itself:

```
>>> l_true=[1,2,3,4,5,3,3,5,6,7,5,4]
>>> any( x==y==3 for x,y in zip( l_true, l_true[1:] ) )
True
>>> l_false=[1,2,3,4,5,3,1,5,6,7,5,4]
>>> any( x==y==3 for x,y in zip( l_false, l_false[1:] ) )
False
```

**Explanation:**

`zip` takes one element at a time of each list, you can compare the list with itself switching one position one of the instances:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,3,3,5,6,7,5,4]
[2,3,4,5,3,3,5,6,7,5,4]  #<-  switched list
           ^
           |
            - here !
```

Maybe it exists a more readable approach, but, `zip` and `any` are Python functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(mylist):
     for i in range(0, len(mylist) - 2):
         if myList[i] == 3 and myList[i] == myList[i+1]: 
             return True
    return False
```

Comment: I copy pasted OPs code. Not a problem on my behalf.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: CBA if OP failed indentation. If you post an answer you should check it. Take responsibility for your action. Now you look like a noob and I guess that is not what your intention was. Just say e.g. "thanks... fixed" and you fix the indentation.. (and yes..once you read my message and see my point you can flag for removal mine and you can remove yours too).